# Why close a question just because the same exact question has been asked and answered before?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

Recently a question was closed because it had been asked and answered before.

I thought this was a forum to express your expertise. Why close a question when you could refer the OP to the previously asked question.

Who is the head cop that says 1) there are enough answers, 2) no more answers could possibly be relevant, and 3) all the answers are correct and no one wants to hear anymore???

Answer (score 3):

Counterpoint: what good does it do to have the exact same question on two different pages, with answers scattered between the two?

If you new information to provide that's not covered by the existing answers, feel free to post it. Your answer would bump the question to the front page where people will see it and have the opportunity to vote or comment on it.

Closing duplicate questions is one of the founding principles of Stack Exchange; see 
https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/ for more information.

Comment: I like your “link”. It says “stop worrying and enjoy some duplication”...in bold lettering. Also, your link says, “there are no perfect questions”.  I like that. My point is who says enough is enough? It appears that having identical questions CAN be helpful. (So you’re saying I can add an answer to a closed question? ...hmmm really?)

Comment: No, you can add answers to the original question, which isn't closed.

Comment: One could add an answer to the original site if you knew it existed. If someone points out there is a duplicate question then you can go add your answer. But If you answer the new question and then someone points out there’s a duplicate question and it’s closed, that doesn’t lead to any discussion.